# Mikrotik cloud router with vlans routing

Tags: routing, vlan, cloud, mikrotik, trunk

I have a MikroTik router configured with 30 VLANs, all passing through a trunk via a bridge.   The router provides internet access via three PPP links with load balancing, and also local services to other switches in the building for each department.

My issue arises with an HIKVISION NVR in VLAN 221 with IP 10.12.221.50, while my IT VLAN is 233, and my laptop's IP is 10.12.233.25.

I've configured a mangle rule allowing the IT VLAN to access the NVR VLAN successfully.

However, when I try to route NVR traffic through a specific PPP link using routing marks, I lose access to the NVR from the IT VLAN, though access is still available via the WAN connection. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please include your working and non-working config.